# Can't get wanted result from SQL query missing condition to eliminate duplicated results

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Hi I am having trouble with one specific SQL query, problem goes like this: i have two tables one has the **items** that are currently inside of one product and the second one is **history** of changes. Every time one item is edited his previous state is saved in history table and time and date of change is written in item_edited column of items table. 
If item gets deleted it is removed from Item table and new line is inserted in history table with last state of item and delete date is written in item_deleted column in history table. If item is not edited item_edited has value NULL and also if item is not deleted item_deleted has value NULL.

I need to write SQL query that will return state of product on specific date(items and there number that were on that date)

Tables

**Items**

```
product_Id (uniqueidentifier,null)  
item_Id (PK,bigint,not null)
item_name (varchar(200),not null)
item_number_of_items (int,null)
item_created (datetime,null)
item_created_by_person (uniqueidentifier,null)  
item_edited (datetime,null)
item_edited_by_person (uniqueidentifier,null)
```

**History**

```
history_Id (PK,bigint,not null)
product_Id (uniqueidentifier,null)  
item_Id (PK,bigint,not null)
item_name (varchar(200),not null)
item_number_of_items (int,null)
item_created (datetime,null)
item_created_by_person (uniqueidentifier,null)  
item_edited (datetime,null)
item_edited_by_person (uniqueidentifier,null)
item_deleted (datetime,null)
```

This is what i have for now, problem is i get duplicated items from history,for example if there are more "edit" states in history for one specific item this query returns all of those states that are before selected date so i get duplicated items in final result. And i need some condition to select from **History** only items that are latest edited before selected date and not deleted before selected date and is not in **Items** table.

```
    DECLARE @selectDate DATETIME 
    SET @selectDate = '2013/05/9' 
    DECLARE @Product_Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
    SET @Product_Id = 'AF4A8D96-2B9B-4C09-8FA3-C6BE20CFD391'

    SELECT item_Id,
           item_name,
           item_number_of_items,
           item_created,
           item_created_by_person,
           item_edited,
           item_edited_by_person
    FROM Items WHERE    product_Id=@Product_Id 
    AND FLOOR(CAST (ISNULL(item_edited,item_created) AS FLOAT)) <= FLOOR(CAST(@selectDate AS FLOAT))

    UNION ALL 

    SELECT item_Id,
           item_name,
           item_number_of_items,
           item_created,
           item_created_by_person,
           item_edited,
           item_edited_by_person
   FROM History 

   WHERE product_Id=@Product_Id 

   AND FLOOR(CAST (ISNULL(item_edited,item_created) AS FLOAT)) <= FLOOR(CAST(@selectDate AS FLOAT))
   AND (FLOOR(CAST(item_deleted AS FLOAT)) > FLOOR(CAST(@selectDate AS FLOAT)) OR item_deleted IS NULL)
   AND item_Id NOT IN (SELECT item_Id FROM item WHERE product_Id=@Product_Id 
                      AND FLOOR(CAST (ISNULL(item_edited,item_created) AS FLOAT)) <= FLOOR(CAST(@selectDate AS FLOAT)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok thanks for you help it actually guided me to a right direction :) Ok this is my solution:

```
CREATE TABLE #ITEMS_CURENTSTATE (item_Id BIGINT,
        item_name VARCHAR(100),
        item_number_of_items INT,
        item_created DATETIME,
        item_edited DATETIME,


CREATE TABLE #ITEMS_EDITED (item_Id BIGINT,
        item_name VARCHAR(100),
        item_number_of_items INT,
        item_created DATETIME,
        item_edited DATETIME,


CREATE TABLE #ITEMS_DELETED (item_Id BIGINT,
        item_name VARCHAR(100),
        item_number_of_componentns INT,
        item_created DATETIME,
        item_edited DATETIME,item_deleted DATETIME,



DECLARE @SELECTDATE DATETIME 
SET @SELECTDATE = '2013/05/29' 
DECLARE @PRODUCT_ID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
SET @PRODUCT_ID = 'F67A7F31-6031-4213-8826-E53E1BC21337'


INSERT INTO #ITEMS_CURENTSTATE

SELECT item_Id,
    item_name,
    item_number_of_items,
    item_created,
    item_edited,
    FROM item WHERE 
PRODUCT_ID=@PRODUCT_ID 
AND FLOOR(CAST (ISNULL(item_edited,item_created) AS FLOAT)) <= FLOOR(CAST(@SELECTDATE AS FLOAT))





INSERT INTO #ITEMS_DELETED

SELECT item_Id,
        item_name,
        item_number_of_items,
        item_created,
        item_edited,item_deleted,


     FROM History WHERE PRODUCT_ID=@PRODUCT_ID AND FLOOR(CAST(item_deleted AS FLOAT)) <= FLOOR(CAST(@SELECTDATE AS FLOAT))



INSERT INTO #ITEMS_EDITED

SELECT  item_Id,
        item_name,
        item_number_of_items,
        item_created,
        item_edited,
     FROM History WHERE PRODUCT_ID=@PRODUCT_ID AND item_Id NOT IN (SELECT item_Id FROM #ITEMS_CURENTSTATE UNION ALL SELECT item_Id FROM #ITEMS_DELETED)
    AND FLOOR(CAST (ISNULL(item_edited,item_created) AS FLOAT)) <= FLOOR(CAST(@SELECTDATE AS FLOAT)) 



    SELECT * FROM #ITEMS_CURENTSTATE

   UNION ALL


    SELECT  A.item_Id,
        A.item_name,
        A.item_number_of_items,
        A.item_created,
        A.item_edited,
         FROM (SELECT item_Id,MAX(ISNULL(item_edited,CAST(0 AS DATETIME))) AS MaxEditDate FROM #ITEMS_EDITED GROUP BY item_Id) B 
        INNER JOIN #ITEMS_EDITED A ON A.item_Id=B.item_Id AND ISNULL(A.item_edited,CAST(0 AS DATETIME))=B.MaxEditDate


    DROP TABLE #ITEMS_CURENTSTATE    
    DROP TABLE #ITEMS_DELETED
    DROP TABLE #ITEMS_EDITED
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it sounds like you are only updating `item_edited` when you edit, and not for inserts or deletes.  It would be better to rename this to `LastModified`, or something like that, and update it for *every* change in state, whether it's the original insert, an edit, or a delete.
Then you could just write.

```
 Select * From History h
 Where item_edited = 
     (Select Max(item_edited)
      From History
      Where item_Id = h.item_Id
          And item_edited < @AsOfDatetime)
```

If you are not, then I hope you are inserting a record into the history table when you initially insert a new row, and that you are inserting a new record with the newe current state every time a record is edited, as opposed to inserting a history row with the old state when an edit is made.  In the former case the current state duplicated and is always the most recent row in the history table, as well as in the current table.

If so, then you could write

```
 Select * From History h
 Where Coalesce(item_deleted, item_edited, item_created) = 
     (Select Max(Coalesce(item_deleted, item_edited, item_created))
      From History
      Where item_Id = h.item_Id
          And item_edited < @AsOfDatetime)
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but this didn't work for me :(  So when item is edited it updates it's state in Item table and writes edit date in item_edited column, it's old state is copied and inserted as a new row to History table.And when item is deleted it is deleted from Items table and it's state is inserted as a new row in History table and also item_ deleted date is written in item_deleted column of history table.So when i do my query i get duplicated results from history that have different history_Id(that's why DISTINCT won't work) and few of them have same item_Id but different dates of editing